# AccessToken expired after an hour even though refresh token is in place - BigQuery Connector 1.0.9 in WSO2 EI 6.5.0

Tags: google-bigquery, oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using [BigQuery Connector V1.0.9](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/bigquery-connector/bigquery-connector-reference/) to work with DataSet,TableData etc in `WSO2 EI 6.5.0`.

- Generated `OAuth` Credentials like `ClientID,ClientSec,AccessToken,RefreshToken` etc
- Added Connector in WSO2 EI Server and enabled it
- passed all above mentioned OAuth param to `bigquery.init` Operation to establish the connectivity.
- After this `init` operation there is some file created under `registry` to store `AccessToken` Value

**bigquery.init - Code:**

```
<!-- Reading BigQuery Credentials -->
            <sequence description="Load Configurations" key="Get_BigQuery_Credentials"/>
            <!-- Establish BigQuery Connectivity -->
            <bigquery.init>
                <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
                <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
                <clientId>{$ctx:clientId}</clientId>
                <clientSecret>{$ctx:clientSecret}</clientSecret>
                <refreshToken>{$ctx:refreshToken}</refreshToken>
                <registryPath>{$ctx:registryPath}</registryPath>
            </bigquery.init>
            <log level="full"/>
```

**WireLog:**

```
    [2023-03-09 17:11:57,785] []  INFO - LogMediator *********BigQueryAPI - OAuth = is called **********
[2023-03-09 17:11:57,788] []  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : Connector/BigQIntegwso2/ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,248] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "GET /oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.XXXXXX HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,249] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "activityid: 3404708f-5eb0-459d-ad1b-b376ddbc4059[\r][\n]"[2023-03-09 17:11:58,249] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,249] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,250] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "Postman-Token: 238c81f0-ca8d-4577-912e-d30116589a73[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,250] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,250] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,250] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "Host: www.googleapis.com[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,250] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,250] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,251] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 << "[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,355] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,355] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,355] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Date: Thu, 09 Mar 2023 11:41:57 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,355] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,356] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,356] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,356] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Vary: Origin[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,356] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Vary: X-Origin[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,356] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Vary: Referer[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,356] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,357] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Server: ESF[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,357] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "X-XSS-Protection: 0[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,357] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,357] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,357] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,357] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,357] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,358] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,358] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0x1f][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,358] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,358] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0x8b][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,358] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,358] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0x8][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,359] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,359] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0x0][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,359] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,360] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0x0][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,360] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,360] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0x0][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,360] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,361] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0x0][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,361] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,361] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0x0][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,361] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,361] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0x2][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,361] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,362] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0xff][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,362] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,362] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0xab][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,362] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,362] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0xe6][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,362] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,362] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "R[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,363] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,363] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "P[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,363] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,364] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "P[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,364] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,364] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "J[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,364] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "00000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,364] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "-[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,365] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "0000001[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,365] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "*[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,365] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "3c[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,365] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[0xca]/R[0xb2]RP[0xca][0xcc]+K[0xcc][0xc9]L[0x89]/[0xc9][0xcf]N[0xcd]S[0xd2][0x81][0xcb][0xc5][0xa7][0xa4][0x16]'[0x17]e[0x16][0x94]d[0xe6][0xe7][0x81][0xd4]yB[0xd4])[0x84]%[0xe6][0x94][0xa6]*q[0xd5]r[0x1][0x0][0x92]_[0xb][0xd2]G[0x0][0x0][0x0][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,365] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "0[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,366] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-6 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,737] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,738] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,738] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,738] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,738] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,738] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,738] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Vary: Origin[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,739] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Vary: X-Origin[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,739] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Vary: Referer[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,739] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,739] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,739] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "X-XSS-Protection: 0[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,740] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,740] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,740] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Host: bigquery.googleapis.com[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,740] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,740] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,741] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,741] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "ff[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,741] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "[0x1f][0x8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0]M[0x8e][0xbb]n[0x83]0[0x0]E[0xbf][0xa6][0xd9]@$`[0x1e][0x3][0x3][0xb8][0x1][0xd2]B qS[0xc1][0x84][0xc0][0x18]b[0xa0][0xd8]1[0x8f][0x88]|}Y*U[0xba][0xdb][0xd1]9[0xba][0x82][0xd4][0x82][0x8c][0xf7]|b[0x1d][0x19][0xec][0xfd][0xdb][0xc1][0xdb][0xa6]TF[0x90][0xbc][0xb7]H[\r][0xca]+[0x82]Mvr[0xae][0x8e][0xe3];[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,741] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << ":?=)[0xb4]Nb[0x8c].[0x91][0xb][0xe1][0xd7][0xfa][0xca]W'E[0xd8][\r][0xc2]g[0xde][0xb9][0x91]0[0x88][0xee]~.C[0x1e]'[0xad][0xc5][0xea]c[0xd1])[0x10][0x9a][0xe0][0xbe]f[0xe1][0x7][0xf7].[0x12][0x2][0xc9]7[0x4][0x98]GY[0xb3]kD1L[0xf9][0xb4]rb[0x8b][0xff]'v[0xb8][0xa7]d##[0xc1][0x82]L[0xb6][0x1f]C[0x94][0xa4][0x92][0x1b][0xd3][0xe5][0xc6]5[0xea][0xd7]^Y=[0x8e]:[0xa2]Io[0xf0][0xdb]9K[0x15][0xfd][0xcf][0xa0][0x95][0xad][0xee][\r][0xd3][0x4][0xaa]u[0x0]@[0x93]*Pj3e[0x1d][0xc0][0x7][0xfe][0xd0]g[0xc1][0x16]R3[0xa0][0xf3]A[0xd1]Z[0xa0][0xea][0x86]\p>[0xca][\r]cMO[0xe6][0x91][0x8][0xcc][0x86]i[0xeb][0xc8][0x98][0xfd][0xfc][0x2][0xc2][0xf9][0xbd][[0x17][0x1][0x0][0x0][\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,741] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "0[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,741] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,898] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,898] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,899] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "Referrer-Policy: no-referrer[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,899] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "Content-Length: 1576[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,899] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "Date: Thu, 09 Mar 2023 11:41:58 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,899] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,899] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,900] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,900] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "<!DOCTYPE html>[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,900] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "<html lang=en>[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,900] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "  <meta charset=utf-8>[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,900] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,900] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,901] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "  <style>[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,901] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,902] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,906] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "  </style>[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,906] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,907] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That[0xe2][0x80][0x99]s an error.</ins>[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,907] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "  <p>The requested URL <code>/oauth2/v3/token</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That[0xe2][0x80][0x99]s all we know.</ins>[\n]"
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,908] [] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:168)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:121)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:146)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:171)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:242)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:242)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:242)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:179)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:805)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:578)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:195)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:265)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:36)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 24 more
[2023-03-09 17:11:58,916] [] ERROR - TemplateMediator Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
```

- After an hour Oauth `Accesstoken` Expired and noticed `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` ERROR in above shared Wirelog.
- Even though we're passing `refreshToken` in `init` Operation, why that accesstoken expired? The main purpose of refresh token is to refresh/regenerate the access token when it expires to make it alive. Correct me if i'm wrong.

I need to manually generate credentials again and update in WSO2 API also. How can we avoid this situation?

PS: Worked with Gmail/Outlook Connector where simlar set of token param are used , this kinda ERROR not happened frequently. But with BigQuery Connector expired every an hour.

Kindly suggest some better way to handle this situation?

Comment: The `init` operation itself has the logic to [renew the access](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-bigquery/blob/master/src/main/resources/bigquery-config/init.xml#L117) token if expired. Did the API calls fail as well? The above wire log is expected since we use the `tokeninfo` endpoint to validate the token

Comment: Hi @sanoJ
Thanks for your time. I have updated Entire wirelog for reference. There is one more API call (POST /oauth2/v3/token) happened in init operation which gives ERROR like HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. that means that token regeneration by using refresh token is not working. right? please check the same

Comment: As @ycr mentioned, you need to change the apiUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token endpoint seems Wrong. Shouldn't it be `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` So change your apiUrl to `https://www.googleapis.com`.

Following is a sample dataset.

```json
{
  "accessToken": "ya29.BwKYx40Dith1DFQBDjZOHNqhcxmKs9zbkjAWQa1q8mdMFndp2-q8ifG66fwprOigRwKSNw",
  "apiUrl": "https://www.googleapis.com",
  "clientId": "504627865627-kdni8r2s10sjddfgXzqb4bvnba.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "clientSecret": "ChlbHI_T7zssXXTRYuqj_-TM",
  "refreshToken": "1/uWful-diQNAdk-alDUa6ixxxxxxxx-LpJIikEQ2sqA",
  "registryPath": "connectors/bq",
  "projectId": "publicdata",
  "datasetId": "samples",
  "fields": "id",
  "callback": "callBackFunction",
  "apiKey": "154987fd5h4x6gh4",
  "prettyPrint": "true",
  "quotaUser": "1hx46f5g4h5ghx6h41x54gh6f4hx",
  "userIp": "192.77.88.12",
  "ifNoneMatch":"hnk59tKBkX8cdlePZ8VtzgVzuO4/tS1oqpXxnkU21hZeK5k4lqRrRr8",
  "ifMatch":"hnk59tKBkX8cdlePZ8VtzgVzuO4/tS1oqpXxnkU21hZeK5k4lqRrRr8"
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-bigquery/blob/master/docs/config.md) document as well.

Comment: Hi @ycr,

As you mentioned, after changing apiUrl as "https://www.googleapis.com", i can get the response now. I'll check whether token regeneration is happening or not within init operation after an hour and confirm you back. Thank you so much for highlighting this

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Yes today without any failure, token still active and process working as expected after i made apiURL change. Once again Thank you